# Is connecting to a database using SqlConnection() AND a Connection string safe?

Tags: c#, dapper, sqlconnection

I am using the following code in conjunction with dapper ORM to connect to a database :

```
using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString()))
{
return db.Query<object>(Sql).ToList();
}
```

The connection string contains database name and login information. I am wondering if while establishing connection to the database server, if any of that information could be visible to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean in transit: you can force SQL Server to use encrypted connections - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067(v=sql.105).aspx

If you mean in-process - the key parts are removed by default so they won't be trivially available to other code with the `SqlConnection` instance; this is related to the "Persist Security Info" parameter on `SqlConnection`'s connection-string, which defaults to false. Basically, the `.ConnectionString` property does not expose the credentials once provided. Note that the `string` will still have existed in memory at some point, so someone with raw access to the process and memory analysis tools may still be able to obtain it; see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx

However, you could also just use Windows authentication via SSPI - this then just uses the app-domain's executing user identity info to connect. Same link as above, but see the "Integrated Security" connection-string parameter.

Answer (score 1):

On the Local Computer: Yes, it would be possible to get access to the information

Over the Network DB Connections: Depends on DB, SQL Server supports SSL, but if you don't use that then you'd be exposing information in your traffic

Answer (score 0):

This would entirely depend on where the connection is being established from and where the connection is being established to.

If either end is in the hands of someone for example, in a distributed client, then they will be able to get hold of the connection details. Typically however, a connection is established "behind the scenes", something like from a web server to a database. Because a connection established like this is all "server side", the connection string is never visible to the "client" of the application and is therefore generally perceived to be safe - of course it is still at the mercy of the infrastructure! :)

It's worth nothing that if this is something like a thick client running on a domain then using something like Windows credentials is an option and would be as secure as the account.